# AJAX Request with empty result - clear our HTML input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select menu that, when a user makes a selection, it fires off an AJAX request to a PHP script to query a database and return a value that matches the selection and inserts this into an associated input field.

This is all working well, however I now need to cater for the possibility that an empty result might be returned (up until now a matching result was always returned). If that is the case it needs to delete the value from the associated input field/clear this input field.

Here's what a successful AJAX request returns (JSON data):

```
[{"senderMobile":"0412 345 678"}]
```

and here's what an empty result returns:

```
[{"senderMobile":""}]
```

Here's the AJAX code that calls the PHP script and updates the input field:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#smsFromName").change(function() {
    var smsFromName = $("#smsFromName").val();
    console.log(smsFromName);
    $.post('getSMSSender.php', {
      senderName: smsFromName
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        alert("error");
        $("#smsFrom").html('');
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
        $("#smsFrom").val(data[0].senderMobile);
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      $("#smsFrom").html('');
    });
  });
});
```

I gather I need to update this section to include an option that if there is no data to simply clear out the #smsFrom input field:

```
} else { 
console.log( data[0].smsFrom );
$("#smsFrom").val(data[0].senderMobile);
```

but I'm stumped at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check if `senderMobile` has a value. Try this:

```
if (data.error) {
    alert("error");
    $("#smsFrom").html('');
    return; // stop executing this function any further
} else if (data[0] && data[0].senderMobile) {
    console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
    $("#smsFrom").val(data[0].senderMobile);
} else {
    $("#smsFrom").val(""); // or .html(""); I didn't get what kind of element is this...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the response data for an empty string.
Code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#smsFromName").change(function() {
    var smsFromName = $("#smsFromName").val();
    console.log(smsFromName);
    $.post('getSMSSender.php', {
      senderName: smsFromName
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        alert("error");
        $("#smsFrom").html('');
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        if(data[0].senderMobile == ""){
           $("#smsFrom").empty();
           continue;
        }else {
         console.log(data[0].smsFrom);
         $("#smsFrom").val(data[0].senderMobile);
         }
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      $("#smsFrom").html('');
    });
  });
});
```